# IPv6 only server PXE provisioning

Tags: ipv6, pxe-boot, mikrotik, dhcpv6

We are currently preparing for IPv6 only network deployment and struggle to find a unique server identification.

In our previous setup, we used mac address as servers primary identification. We were then able to assign the server always the same address.

E.g. we needed to perform upgrade from wheezy to jessie and rather then apt-get dist-upgrade, we reinstalled the server. As we use puppet for configuration, it all took 15 minutes and server was up, fresh and perfectly running again with the same IP and DNS name.

Unfortunately, we are currently not able to achieve this with IPv6 as the server with every OS (Linux, PXEBoot kernel, ...) has different DUID, which means for every OS different IPv6 address.

In our setup, we use mikrotik as DHCP server.

How would you manage situation like this?

**Update #1**: It seems it is currently not possible:

- https://www.insinuator.net/2015/02/is-rfc-6939-support-finally-here-checking-the-implementation-of-the-client-link-layer-address-option-in-dhcpv6/
- http://blog.bronislavrobenek.com/post/64383333742/ipv6-security-in-enterprise-network

I was able to find a patch (http://alter.org.ua/soft/fbsd/isc_dhcpd/) for isc-dhcp-server that fixes this, but it is not global solution and I can't apply that on cisco or mikrotik devices.

**Update #2**: We have decided to leave mikrotik platform as we outgrown the capabilities of this platform. We are currently preparing new "infrastructure" server based on linux, that will run https://dhcpy6d.ifw-dresden.de/ (besides other services such as openvpn for ipmi, ...).

Comment: You mean that on each re-install of the OS (or booting different OS on the same machine) the DUID is different each time?

Comment: That is correct. Every OS reinstall has different DUID.

Comment: Sounds like what you are asking for is a DHCPv6 server, which uses the MAC address to decide which address to assign to the client (and ignore the DUID). If that's what you are looking for, then switching to another DHCPv6 server might be an option. Another option is to use SLAAC with addresses based on MAC address rather assigning addresses through DHCPv6.

Comment: SLACC can use a modified EUI-64 interface ID which is derived from the MAC address so should be usable for this purpose. The automatic link local IPv6 address generation uses this method.

Comment: are you able to use dhcp6-relay and have a dhcp3-server running on another network?

Comment: Thinking about SLACC I can see a problem with multiple interfaces. Every interface will be assigned an address and I will not be very much in charge of setting which will be used as a active one for outgoing connections.

Comment: Today, I found this presentation http://indico.cern.ch/event/251056/session/1/contribution/12/attachments/436305/605467/dhcpv6.pdf There is an option 79 (OPTION_CLIENT_LINKLAYER_ADDR) descibed by rfc6939 in DHCPv6 which should provide mac address on relay agents. Therefore the solution might be to use mikrotik/cisco only as relay agents and ISC-DHCP server to manage the assignments.

Comment: A MAC address aware DHCPv6 server: https://dhcpy6d.ifw-dresden.de/